# jquery get value with '&' character

Tags: jquery

I have a textbox which has value like "PN & J".I am storing it in

```
var sState = $('#txtState').val();
```

and making Ajax call by

```
  data: 'Service=' + sSvendor + '&City=' + sCity + '&Sub=' + sCitySub + '&State=' + sState + '&Network=' + sNetwork,
```

But at the receiving end i m retrieving Value as only `"PN "` it is neglecting string after `'&'` character. how to overcome this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `&` is the seperator of `key=value` pairs in a GET request, you need to escape it using [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent);

```
data: 'Service=' + sSvendor + '&City=' + sCity + '&Sub=' + sCitySub + '&State=' + encodeURIComponent(sState) + '&Network=' + sNetwork,
```

Of note, there's also [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI), but that doesn't encode values like `&` (as it treats the input as a whole URI, rather than a particular component).

Feel free to escape the rest of the values yourself for security... I'm just too lazy.

Comment: might be worth pointing out that you've misnamed both encode-functions in your links.

Comment: @DavidHedlund: Eugh, thanks. I got it right in the code sample though, god knows what I was thinking/ typing... TGIF :P

Answer (score 3):

If you concatenate the string yourself like that, you need to make sure you escape the values properly:

```
state = encodeURIComponent(sState)
```

But this will be taken care of for you if you serialize a form, or set the data to a JSON object.

```
data = { state: sState, ... }
```

or

```
data = $('#some-form').serialize()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `encodeURIComponent()` to encode the characters.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript) for more details